# An "explicit" description of cocomma-categories ?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let the cocomma-square $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>T>> Y\\
    @V S V  V \Uparrow_\beta  @VV i_1 V\\
    X @>>i_0> (S\star T)
\end{CD}

where :

- $Ob\,(S\star T) :=Ob\,X\sqcup Ob\,Y$

and $\hom_{(S\star T)}(r,r') $ is given by :

- $\hom_{(S\star T)}(r,r'):=\hom_{X}(x,x')$ if $r=x, r'=x' \in X$,
- $\hom_{(S\star T)}(r,r'):=\hom_{Y}(y,y')$ if $r=y, r'=y' \in Y$,
- $\emptyset$ if $r\in Y$ and $r'\in X$,
- for all $a\in A$, a formal arrow : $Sa \overset{\underline{a}}{\longrightarrow} Ta  $ such that : $id_{Ta}\circ \underline{a}=\underline{a}\circ id_{Sa}=\underline{a}$

all this arrows subject to the relations :

- if $r=x\in X$ and $r'=y\in Y$,  two parallel arrows of $\hom_{(S\star T)}(x,y)$ :

$$x\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}Sa\overset{\underline{a}}{\longrightarrow}Ta\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}y$$

$$x\overset{f'}{\longrightarrow}Sa'\overset{\underline{a}'}{\longrightarrow}Ta'\overset{g'}{\longrightarrow}y$$

are equal if exists a "zig-zag" in $A$ : 
$$a\overset{q_{1}}{\longleftarrow}a_{1}\longrightarrow...\overset{q_{n}}{\longrightarrow}a' $$
and arrows $f_{i}:x\longrightarrow Sa_{i}$ in $X$ and $g_{i}:Ta_{i}\longrightarrow y$ in $Y$ making the diagram commutes  :
\begin{CD}
x @>f>>    Sa @>\underline{a}>> Ta @>g>> y \\
 @|   @A Sq_1 AA         @AA Tq_1 A  @| \\
x @>f_1>>  Sa_1 @>>\underline{a_1}> Ta_1   @>g_1>> y \\
@|   @V Sq_2 VV   @VV Tq_2 V @| \\
\cdots @>>> \cdots @>>> \cdots   @>>> \cdots \\
@| @V Sq_n VV   @VV Tq_n V @| \\
x @>>f'>  Sa' @>>\underline{a'}> Ta' @>>g'> y\\
\end{CD}

In this description : $\beta_a:=\underline{a}$.

Can someone confirm me if it is right or not ?

Comment: I guess your question is: how can we represent the pushout of $X \leftarrow A \to Y$ better? If this is correct, then your description of the objects of $S\star T$ is wrong: the functor $|\bullet|$ sending  a small category $\cal C$ into its set of objects $|{\cal C}|$ is cocontinuous (it is a left adjoint) so that $|S\star T|\cong |X|\amalg_{|A|}|Y|$, which is a (rather nontrivial, since $S,T$ are arbitrary functors) quotient of $|X|\amalg |Y|$.

Comment: It seems to me that your argument is ok for the pushout but in my case it's  the "lax pushout".

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right, but I have to think about it.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for the spirit of your reply !

Comment: This is a standard comment to inform you that I updated my answer to put it in-topic :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Even if my main goal is to produce a easy-readable presentation for those who don't know a lot of categorical concept (in particular : young students, physicists, engineers), it's good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your construction is basically correct.  The only slight mistake (probably you had the correct thing in mind and this was just a mistake in phrasing) is that the formal arrows $\underline{a}$ are not sufficient to give the hom-sets $\hom_{S\star T}(r,r')$ when $r\in X$ and $r'\in Y$; you also need the "formal composites" of these arrows with arrows in $X$ and $Y$ on either side, which then get quotiented by the equivalence relation you describe.

Here is an abstract argument for why this construction is correct.

1. Every comma object is a discrete [two-sided fibration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-sided+fibration).
2. Dually, every cocomma object is a [codiscrete two-sided cofibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiscrete+cofibration).
3. In Cat, every discrete two-sided fibration is the comma of its cocomma, and every codiscrete two-sided cofibration is the cocomma of its comma.  This sets up an equivalence between discrete two-sided fibrations and codiscrete two-sided cofibrations, both of which represent [profunctors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor) from $Y$ to $X$.
4. Moreover, the comma of the cocomma is a reflection from arbitrary spans into discrete two-sided fibrations, and dually the cocomma of the comma is a coreflection from arbitrary cospans into codiscrete two-sided cofibrations.  Thus, to compute an arbitrary cocomma, it suffices to compute the reflection of a span into discrete two-sided fibrations, regard it as a profunctor, and then take the [collage](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/collage) of that profunctor.
5. Every span $X \leftarrow A \to Y$ generates a free two-sided fibration $X \leftarrow X^{\mathbf{2}}\times_X A \times_Y Y^{\mathbf{2}} \to Y$, where $X^{\mathbf{2}}$ is the category of arrows in $X$.  The objects of this free two-sided fibration are therefore triples $(a,f,g)$ where $a\in A$, $f:x\to S a$, and $g:T a \to y$, which we can regard as the above "formal composites".  Now it suffices to take the discrete reflection of this over $X$ and $Y$, which amounts to imposing your zig-zag equivalence relation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you know some references about cocomma cat ? I need to understand deeply exacts squares à la Guitart and cocomma categories appear naturally in this context.

Comment: There are a few references at the nlab pages I linked to, and the page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+square also mentions cocommas (though it is sadly devoid of references).

Comment: Hi Thanks. Do you mean represent in some sort of Yoneda sense? I'm wondering if you could provide more explanation of the sentence "Thus, to compute an arbitrary cocomma, it suffices to compute the reflection of a span into discrete two-sided fibrations, regard it as a profunctor, and then take the collage of that profunctor"

Comment: @edenstar By "represent profunctors" I mean that the categories of discrete two-sided fibrations and codiscrete two-sided cofibrations are both equivalent to the category of profunctors.  What part of the sentence do you want more explanation of?  Are you wondering what it means or why it is true?

Answer (score 4):

There is an explicit description of colimits in $\bf Cat$: this, however, does not address your question since you are coping with a lax colimit.

Since I am a rather stubborn when it comes to using coend calculus to clarify something, I'm here again with a suggestion on how to look at your construction in a way I like.
Of course, Mike's answer is perfectly fine: this is an equivalent, if not more verbose, way to present your $S\star T$.

Since this construction, as a lax (or colax? Mike had a wonderful mnemonic trick to distinguish the two) pushout, is not symmetric in $S,T$, and since this reflects a morphological principle I really care about[1], I'll stick to denote your $\star$ as $\ltimes $

==

Right before the section "Using comma object" on the [$n$Lab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+square) about exact squares there is the claim

> the cocomma object of a cospan $Y\overset{u}{\leftarrow} A \overset{f}{\to} X$ is precisely the cograph of the profunctor $Y(u,1) \circ X(1,f)$.

Let's prove this statement. First of all we have to look closer at the definition of the "cograph": following again [$n$Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cograph+of+a+profunctor) this is the category having objects the disjoint union $B\coprod C$ and arrows those of $B$, in the copy of $B$, those of $C$, in the copy of $C$, no arrows between $c$ and $b$, and exactly as many arrows as 
$$
\int^a Y(ga,c)\times X(b, fa)
$$
between $b\in B$ and $c\in C$. This coend powerfully encodes all the cumbersome generators of equivalence relations you would have to write if you didn't know how to write an integral symbol :-)

The intuition for what's into $\hom_{X\ltimes Y}(b,c)$ is precisely the same as above! It's a set of "fake arrows"
$$
b \xrightarrow{\varphi} fa \overset{(\xi)}\rightsquigarrow ga \xrightarrow{\psi}c
$$
where the arrow $(\xi)$ exists "morally". I suspect that (and there's some homotopy theory going on here, I think[2]) you would have obtained the same category up-to-equivalence defining $X\ltimes Y$ to be the strict pushout
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A \coprod A & \to & A \times {\bf 2}\\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
X\coprod Y & \to & P
\end{array}
$$
if you look closer you'll see what is really "creating" the fake arrows, but my point is that *you shouldn't* because coends are far better behaved quotients. :-)

Inside the coend, you identify two arrows $b \xrightarrow{\varphi} fa \overset{(\xi)}\rightsquigarrow ga \xrightarrow{\psi}c$ and $b \xrightarrow{\varphi} fa' \overset{(\xi')}\rightsquigarrow ga' \xrightarrow{\psi}c$ precisely when there is a zig-zag $a\leftrightarrows a'$ fitting in the diagram with which you opened the thread.

==

Now we have enough material to fiddle and find the universal property: a natural transformation $\zeta\colon i_0 S \Rightarrow i_1 T$ comes from the tautological equivalence class of identities in the following way.

Since $\zeta_a : i_o fa \to i_1 ga$ is an arrow $fa \to ga$ when the two objects are regarded in $X\ltimes Y$, we have to find a distinguished element in $\hom_{X\ltimes Y}(fa, ga)$, or rather in the coend above where $c=ga, b=fa$. This gives the image of $(1_{ga}, 1_{fa}) \in Y(ga,ga)\times X(fa,fa)$ under the composition
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hom(ga,ga)\times \hom(fa,fa) &\ni&(1_{ga}, 1_{fa})\\
\downarrow\\
\coprod_{a\in A}\hom(c,ga)\times \hom(fa, b)\\
\downarrow\\
\hom_{X\ltimes Y}(fa, ga) &\ni& [(1_{ga}, 1_{fa})]
\end{array}
$$
as a natural candidate for $\zeta_a \colon fa\to ga$. And in fact this works!

Suppose you are given a commutative square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A &\to & B \\
\downarrow &\Downarrow  & \downarrow\\
C &\to&Y
\end{array}
$$
filled by a 2-cell $\theta : wf \Rightarrow vg$. Then define a unique functor $u : X\ltimes Y \to Y$ on objects and true arrows in $B$ or $C$ acting as $v\colon C\to Y, w\colon B\to Y$; the action of $u$ on a fake arrow
$$
b \xrightarrow{\varphi} fa \overset{(\xi)}\rightsquigarrow ga \xrightarrow{\psi}c
$$
is induced by the composition
$$
wb \xrightarrow{w\varphi} wfa \xrightarrow{\theta_a} vga \xrightarrow{v\psi}vc
$$
(all arrows exist now!), and I'm more than happy to leave you a bunch of routine checks ($u$ is unique due to the tautological definition of $\zeta$; $\zeta$ has a 2-dimensional universal property as well; $\zeta\circ -$ reflects isos).

Some obvious remarks:

1. Flip $X$ and $Y$, you obtain the opposite construction with a 2-cell in the opposite direction.
2. That's awesome! The cograph of a profunctor is the category of elements of the same profunctor regarded as a presheaf $B^\text{op}\times C \to {\rm Set}$. This reinforces the inuition of $\text{Elts}(F)$ as a suitable lax colimit of the presheaf $F$. The consequences of this never stop to fill me with wonder.
3. What if $f$ or $g$ is the identity functor? You get the category of elements of $Y(g,1)$ or $X(1,f)$, which is...
4. What's the cograph of $\hom(f,g)$ and how does it fit into this constructions?

===

[1] i.e. the idea that (non-)commutative operations deserve (non-)symmetric symbols.

[2]there's some *directed* homotopy theory going on, to be precise. See Grandis, "Directed Algebraic Topology: Models of Non-Reversible Worlds"
Volume 13 di New Mathematical Monographs.